# how to link to a page with picked item from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-select

I'm using react-select for my web application
I have a dropdown with autofill, when I click on input I will see a list of all the car items that come from API but I need to enter the needed one and redirect to that details page.
Should I create route for this ?

Take a look:
[image]

When I click on BMW I need to go to bmw detials page.
if it was just simple car item I would create a button under and Link

```
<Link  className='btn-item auction-btn mr-2' to={`/carDetails/${item.id}`}>Details</Link>.
```

with routing:

```
 <Route
            exact
            path="/carDetails/:id"
            render={({ match }) => (
              <CarDetails item={data.find((item) => String(item.id) === String(match.params.id))} />
            )}
          />
```

but this is react-select library and it's component that I have to filter and than to go to that page I need ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `history.push` in change handler of react-select. An example:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  const history = useHistory()

  function handleChange(newValue) {
    setValue(newValue)
    history.push(`/carDetails/${newValue.id}`)
  }

  return (
    <Select
      value={value}
      options={options}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Also, you may not need `setValue(newValue)` in change handler if you are leaving the current component and redirecting to other component using `history.push`.

Comment: idk why but (`/carDetails/${newValue.id}`) is undefined

Comment: {label: "Ferrari California", value: "Ferrari California"}
label: "Ferrari California"
value: "Ferrari California"

Comment: the undefined is when it's redirected to `carDetails/${newValue.id}`

Comment: That means you don't have `id` in `options` you passed to `react-select`. Can you add `id` to your `options`? After that it should work.